# How do I change the orientation of a falling block disguised as a minecraft:rail

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command:

`/summon minecraft:armor_stand 172.5 56.5 -242.5 {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:falling_block",BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:rail"},NoGravity:1b,Time:-2147483648}]}`

I need to figure out how to make it so that the rail is facing east, rather than south. I can not seem to figure this out at all. Somebody told me I could add 'Data:2' at the end but that didn't work, I even tried placing [facing=east] inside the Name:"minecraft:rail" tag. Nothing seems to work for me and I can't find anybody having the same problem.

Ps. I am on Minecraft 1.16.5

Answer (score 1):

1. The correct block state for an east-west facing rail is `shape=east_west`, not `facing=east`
2. Block states in Falling Sand go in the `Properties` subtag, not as part of the `Name` subtag.

The correct command to summon a rail facing east is:

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:falling_block",BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:rail",Properties:{"shape":"east_west"}},NoGravity:1b,Time:-2147483648}]}
```